# AWS SES failing with "Recipient count exceeds 50." on individual recipient emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

We are looping on 160 email addresses in AWS Lambda and calling SES' send_raw_email() API call with one address per call.  After 50 loops we get the error "Recipient count exceeds 50." but there is only one recipient per call.  The other information in the emails, other than "To:", are the same between calls.  We do this to keep recipients from seeing the addresses of other recipients.

Are the emails being batched at SES?  (How are we even hitting this limit?)

How can we get past this error?

Adding code:

```
for item in recipients['Items']:
    RECIPIENT = item['email']['S']
    
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = ses.send_raw_email(
            Source=SENDER,
            Destinations=[
                RECIPIENT
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            }
        )
    # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
    except ClientError as e:
        print("failed to send email: ",e.response['Error']['Message'])
        return {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'body': json.dumps(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    }
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
        print(response['MessageId'])
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying bulk recipients as BCC?

Comment: Check what you are sending to SES by logging exactly what is being sent. Perhaps the TO field is being appended, rather than replaced? Can you show us some simplified code?

Comment: Code snippet added

Comment: Quick testing shows a growing list on the TO line.  Nice call. Now how does one clear the TO list of the message?

Comment: Are you indents correct? It is processing all recipients in a loop, and then only calling `send_raw_email()` once. That wouldn't cause this specific problem, but it looks wrong.

Comment: sorry the indentation formatting is messed up in the post - fixing

Comment: Thanks guys your suggestions got us to the answer.  You have to del msg['To'] before setting msg['To'] = RECIPIENT.

Comment: @bill, If you got to a working solution, can I suggest you post an answer to your question? This will help others who come after you quickly find the answer

Comment: The answer is in the comment above - the library doesn't replace the To by making an assignment it adds to it so the list kept growing.  "del msg['To']" was the key.  I'll post the updated code as an answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the library operates by adding to the "To" list when assigning, not replacing.  So a "del msg['To']" was needed.

```
for item in recipients['Items']:
    RECIPIENT = item['email']['S']

del msg['To']
msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
...
```